# Why is the uBlock Chrome extension blocking my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JavaScript web application that has a search form and loads a Highcharts chart. I'm not using a framework, just plain jQuery and JavaScript classes.

But when I try to load the page in Chrome I get: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

If I go to the muBlock [uBlock](https://chrismatic.io/ublock/) extension (which I really like generally) and whitelist the script, it works OK.

But why is uBlock blocking my JavaScript? It's not an advertisement script nor intended to be - it just reads the hash and sets up a web form, then handles click events to fetch some data from the same domain via Ajax and set up a highcharts chart. None of the classes or methods are called `advert`, `ad` or anything similar.

It's possible that the code is doing something dangerous that I haven't spotted, but how can I figure out what this is?

Apologies, I know it would be good to post a link to the code here, but I can't do that just yet.

Comment: Are you loading all scripts from your own domain, or do you embed library files from some kind of CDN? Also, what specific resource are you getting the quoted error message for?

Comment: Thanks. All the scripts are from my own domain. The specific error is for a script called `analyse.js` which is the very last script to be loaded. Perhaps uBlock doesn't like the name `analyse`... I'll try changing it and see if that helps...

Comment: ...update: yup, renaming it from `analyse` fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uBlock also blocks files named `analyse.js`. If you're having this problem try renaming your local files.